# Hammer.js and disabling click/ tap event until dragging / swipe ended

Tags: jquery, events, click, hammer.js

This is my first time using Hammer.js to get a swipping/dragging slider working on a tablet.

The slider works well but the issue I'm having is that each of the LI items that make up the slider contain a anchor link so when you swipe left/right and remove your finger before the swipe has finished the anchor tag link is triggered and takes the user to another page.

I guess what needs to happen is while the swipe/drag is occurring the anchor/click is disabled and only active when there is no swiping/dragging.

The code is below

```
myhammer = Hammer(element).on("release dragleft swipeleft dragright tap", function (ev)         {
ev.gesture.preventDefault();
switch (ev.type) {
           case 'dragright': case 'swiperight':
                ev.gesture.stopDetect();
                ev.preventDefault();


                //left_value = item_width * (-1);
                //get the right position            
                var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

                //slide the item            
                $('#slides ul').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 200, function () {
                    etc...
                });

                //cancel the link behavior            
                return false;


}

});
```

Comment: I've added this within the case statement and it seems to resolve the premature clicking action   $(".my-nav-li a").click(function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        // do something
                    });